# Possible to change the an 'absolute' location in a .properties files?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Possible to change the an 'absolute' location in a .properties files?

For example if you look at the example below i need to change: `C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\TestFramework` to the current projects folder using a dynamic locator, i know its possible in java using: `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

```
    log4j.appender.R.File=C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\TestFramework\\log\\logFile.log
log4j.appender.TTCC.File=C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\TestFramework\\log\\logFileSystemTime.log
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file location can be a relative path.

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log/console.log
```

You can also use system properties

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${my.prop}/console.log
```

Comment: thanks for the help, in my case how would i replace the following: C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\TestFramework\\?